# Dividing a big text file to short files

Tags: algorithm, perl, text-files

I want to divide (or split) a big txt file into short txt files, for example I have `file.txt` and it's 700 MB, and I want to divide it into seven (100 MB) txt files.

What am I going to do?  Is there any way to divide it without opening the text file and change the content of text file? If there are known algorithms for this problem, please share them. 
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just in case it applies to your environment and needs, the standard Unix solution is to use `split`:

```
split -C 100M input.txt
```

`-C` forces split to split by line instead of byte/char. Use `-b` instead if you prefer to split at a specific byte.

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach -

1. Get the file length, decide the chunk size
2. See how many files you want to create - (n = file length/ chunk size). If any remainder, number of files would be n + 1.
3. Open the file in read mode.
4. Create a file in write mode. (probably append a suffix 1..n to indicate a fragment)
5. write chunk number of bytes (or remainder bytes if remainder < chunk size) to the file, close this file.
6. repeat 4-5 for n fragments.

Comment: If the file size was not evenly divisible by the chunk size, what would you recommend for the final fragment?

Comment: @Garry - Yeah..but this should be easy to detect once OP is able to implement above :P.. On serious note - correcting it

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  The handling the tail condition  has always been troublesome for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on unix

`split -b100m filename part` will split filename into parta, partb, partc etc

Answer (score 0):

In case, you want to have both options of splitting by size and by number of line (which in some cases you need) and it is in Windows environment, you may use a program called GSplit. I once had this problem and it worked for me. You can google it to download.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl distribution includes a split utility, if you happen to not be on Unix.  It uses -l for line split.